# Splitting a touch sequence between multiple UIGestureRecognizer instances

Tags: iphone, ipad, drag-and-drop, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm developing an iPhone/iPad app that supports dragging items between table views. Since all the tables don't fit on screen, I've written a custom `UIScrollView` that lays them out horizontally, and supports paging.

While I've gotten the primary drag and drop together, there are a few remaining issues I can't get past.

1. After the user has selected an item to drag, and is dragging, they cannot scroll the `UIScrollView` to find the destination `UITableView`.
2. Sometimes the user will want to drag the item *within* the same table view. But once the drag has begun, the table view no longer recognizes the scroll gesture.

I've tried a variety of different options, including implementing a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and allowing multiple gesture recognizers to recognize gestures simultaneously.

The problem, as I see it stems from this description from the Event Handling Guide: "iOS recognizes one or more fingers touching the screen as part of a multitouch sequence. This sequence begins when the first finger touches down on the screen and ends when the last finger is lifted from the screen."

`UIGestureRecognizer` instances always match against the entire *sequence*. In my case, I want to split a single sequence down into discrete gestures -- some touches recognize a dragging of an item, while different touches within the same sequence should be recognized as a swipe or scroll gesture. Effectively, I want my gesture recognizers to recognize simultaneously, but only *different* touches. Once one recognizes a touch as part of a gesture, that touch should be ignored by the others.

I haven't found a way to solve all these issues coherently using the default `UIGestureRecognizer` subclasses, and am now about to write my own custom mutli-part gesture recognizer.

I'd rather not have to though -- is there any more appropriate way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the silence here, and a blog post I just found, I believe the answer is that, no there is no way to do sub-gesture recognition with the standard framework.

For those looking to do something similar, take a look at this project/blog post, which is an attempt to create a sub-gesture recognition library:

http://sunetos.com/items/2010/10/31/adding-subgestures-to-ios-gesture-recognition/

I haven't used it -- I ended up manually crafting my own iteractions -- but will consider refactoring to use it if it pans out.